# Whys is this data table cell reverting to old value when I edit another cell in the same row?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm working with a jQuery data table that a previous developer set up. For the columns that are editable, whenever you double click on the value, change it, and hit return, the corresponding record in a database table is updated via AJAX. But one field in the data table always seems to revert to an older, apparently stored value when this happens.

This column is an error message. What happens is, the data table is initially populated from a DB query that gets a record that failed validation when submitted. So maybe the email address was invalid, and the data table will show you the record, along with the bad email address, and the error message from the API saying "bad email address". So you update the email address by dbl-clicking, changing it, and hitting return. That updates the record in the staging table in the DB, and now it's ready to be resubmitted to the API.

I set up a button and a jQuery function to resubmit to the API. So you click that button, and the corrected record in that DB staging table is pulled and submitted. But say there's another problem with the record, like the SSN is invalid. The API will catch it and reply with a new error message, and my function captures the API's response and updates the DB staging table and the data table accordingly. Now on screen you see the data table with that row updated; it has a new error message, which my function changed in the `<td>` element using `$('#errorMessageTD').text(newErrorMessageFromAPI)`.

Here's where the problem happens - now if you dbl-click into the SSN value, change it to a valid SSN, and hit return, then the old "invalid email address" message instantly replaces the SSN error message in that `<td>`. In the DB staging table, the error message remains as the SSN error message, so the value isn't getting pulled from there. So I figure what must be happening is, using the text() function as above replaces the error message that the user sees inside that `<td>` element, but does not replace the text that the jQuery data table has stored for that column and row. OR, it's not that the value is stored in the data table per se, but obviously the value's being stored somewhere. So when you edit another cell in that row and hit return, the contents of the `<td>` are replaced with the original text of when the table was first rendered to screen.

So what I'm wondering is, how can I make the new error message remain in that `td` when a field is edited and the enter button is hit? And why would this one `<td>` revert back, when all other `<td>`'s in the row remain the same, even if they've been edited?

Related code below. In this case, the error message column is column [0] in the aoColumnDefs, and is not an editable field. This data table is initially populated from a query of the staging DB table, and it seems to be this initial value that the `<td>` goes back to whenever you hit enter to edit a field in the same row.

```
// Data Table Scripts for Mass Uploader
var oTable;
var editRowID;
var editText;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').dataTable({
        // Set the column names for saving to the database
        // The number of these settings need to be the same as the number of TRs and TDs in the table
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {"sWidth": "150px", "aTargets":[0]},
            {"sWidth": "60px","sName": "appl_fname", "aTargets":[1]},
            {"sWidth": "50px","sName": "appl_mname","aTargets":[2]},
            {"sWidth": "70px","sName": "appl_lname","aTargets":[3]},
            {"sWidth": "75px","sName": "appl_street","aTargets":[4]},
            {"sWidth": "60px","sName": "appl_street2","aTargets":[5]},
            {"sWidth": "60px","sName": "appl_city","aTargets":[6]},
            {"sWidth": "45px","sName": "appl_state","aTargets":[7]},
            {"sWidth": "45px","sName": "appl_zip","aTargets":[8]},
            {"sWidth": "80px","sName": "appl_dob","aTargets":[9]},
            {"sWidth": "80px","sName": "appl_ssn","aTargets":[10]},
            {"sWidth": "80px","sName": "appl_phone","aTargets":[11]},
            {"sWidth": "120px","sName": "appl_email_box","aTargets":[12]},
            {"sWidth": "120px","aTargets":[13]},
            {"sWidth": "120px","aTargets":[14]},
            {"sWidth": "120px","aTargets":[15]},
            {"sWidth": "50px","sName": "job_id","aTargets":[16]},
            {"sWidth": "80px","sName": "start_date","aTargets":[17]},
            {"sWidth": "60px","sName": "pay_rate","aTargets":[18]},
            {"sWidth": "70px","sName": "base_salary","aTargets":[19]},
            {"sWidth": "70px","sName": "position_type","aTargets":[20]},
            {"sWidth": "100px","sName": "benefit_status","aTargets":[21]},
            {"sWidth": "80px","sName": "status","aTargets":[22]},
            {"sWidth": "80px","sName": "reportsToRecLoginId","aTargets":[23]},
            {"sWidth": "80px","sName": "Send_Welcome_Email","aTargets":[24]},
            {"sWidth": "80px","sName": "Stage_To_Save_To_ID","aTargets":[25]},
            {"sWidth": "120px","aTargets":["SSCustomField"]}
        ],
        //"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        "sScrollXInner": "120%",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bScrollCollapse": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bFilter": false
    }).makeEditable({
        // Set what columns are editable
        // The number of these settings need to be the same as the number of TRs and TDs in the table
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
                {},
                {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            null,
            null,
            null,
            {},
            {},
            {type: 'select',
                onblur: 'submit',
                data: "{'':'Please select...', '1':'Per Hour','2':'Per Year'}",
                event: 'dblclick'},
            {},
            {type: 'select',
                onblur: 'submit',
                data: "{'':'Please select...', '1':'Full Time','2':'Part Time','-1':'Other'}",
                event: 'dblclick'},
            {type: 'select',
                onblur: 'submit',
                data: "{'':'Please select...', '1':'Full Company Benefits','2':'Employee Contribution Benefits','3':'Employee Paid Benefits','4':'No Benefits','-1':'Other'}",
                event: 'dblclick'},
            {type: 'select',
                onblur: 'submit',
                data: "{'':'Please select...', '1':'Exempt','2':'Non-Exempt','-1':'Other'}",
                event: 'dblclick'},
            /*{},*/
            null,//make ReportsTo not editable
            null,//make Send Welcome Email not editable
            /*{type: 'select',
                onblur: 'submit',
                data: "{'':'Please select...', 'true':'Yes','false':'No'}",
                event: 'dblclick'},*/
            /*{type: 'select',
                onblur: 'submit',
                data: "{'':'Please select...', '9':'Completed','8':'Onboarding'}",
                event: 'dblclick'},*/
            null,//make Status to Save To Not Editable
            {}
            /*{}*/
        ],
        fnOnDeleted: function(status) {
            oTable.fnDraw();
        },
        fnOnEditing: function(input, oEditableSettings, sOriginalText, id) {
            editRowID = id;
            editText = sOriginalText;
            return true;
        },
        fnOnEdited: function(status, sOldValue, sNewCellDisplayValue, aPos0, aPos1, aPos2) {
            if(aPos2 == 16 && editText == sOldValue && sNewCellDisplayValue.trim() != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Admin/MassUpload/GetLocationDepartmentPosition.cfm",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {JobID: sNewCellDisplayValue, ErrorRowID: editRowID},
                    success: function (data) {
                        var stringData = data.DATA.toString();
                        if (stringData.length > 0) {
                            var locationPosition, departmentPosition, positionPosition;
                            locationPosition = 'Row'+editRowID+'Location';
                            $('#'+locationPosition).text(data.DATA[0][4]);
                            departmentPosition = 'Row'+editRowID+'Department';
                            $('#'+departmentPosition).text(data.DATA[0][2]);
                            positionPosition = 'Row'+editRowID+'Position';
                            $('#'+positionPosition).text(data.DATA[0][6]);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                        console.log(thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        sUpdateURL: "Admin/MassUpload/UpdateDataTableRow.cfm",
        sDeleteURL: "Admin/MassUpload/DeleteDataTableRow.cfm"
    });

    $('#demo').submit( function() {
        var sData = $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize();
        this.submit();
        return false;
    });

    /* Add a click handler to the rows - this could be used as a callback */
    $("#example tbody tr").click( function( e ) {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
        } else {
            oTable.$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
        }
    });

    /* Add a click handler for the delete row */
    $('#delete').click( function() {
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
        oTable.fnDeleteRow( anSelected[0] );
    });

    oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
    setTimeout(function(){
        oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
    },100);
});
```

Also, below is the function I wrote to resubmit corrected errors to the API, and to update the td with the new error message from the API:

```
processData = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Admin/MassUpload/processErrorsThroughAPI.cfm",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("data stringified: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            if (data.length > 0) {//There are rows in the table to delete or error messages to update
                $.each(data, function(index, item){
                    if (item.ERRORMESSAGE == "") {//Record passed validation. Remove this row from the data table.
                        oTable.fnDeleteRow($('#'+item.IMPORTERRORID)[0]);
                        oTable.fnDraw();
                    }
                    else {//Record did not pass validation, display new error message in the data table
                        $('#Row'+item.IMPORTERRORID+'ErrorMsg').text(item.ERRORMESSAGE);
                    }
                    //console.log(index);
                    console.log("item.IMPORTERRORID = " + item.IMPORTERRORID);
                    console.log("item.ERRORMESSAGE = " + item.ERRORMESSAGE);
                });
            }
            else {//No items to process, so nothing to display
                var divInfo = '<div class="container-fluid"> <div class="row-fluid"> <div class="well well-clear span6 offset3">';
                divInfo += 'Any errors associated with the uploading of the spreadsheet have been corrected.<br/>';
                divInfo += '<button type="button" onclick="selectExcelFile()">Go back to hire import</button><br/>';
                divInfo += '</div> </div> </div>';
                $('#hireImportTab').html(divInfo);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: We need to see the related code segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a couple weeks being completely stumped, here's the fix.

First, the code that makes this Data Table editable appears to come from a branch on GitHub - https://github.com/ansballard/jquery-datatables-editable.

Second, the undesired behavior described in this post seems to be inherent. For a given row in your table, you can change the text of a td element using jQuery:

```
$('#myTDCell_row1').text('Here is some new text');
```

But after that, if you edit any other cell in that td's same row by double-clicking on the cell's contents, typing something new, and hitting the "enter" key, that cell's text will revert to whatever it was before.

I'm not sure why that is, but fortunately, in the jQuery code where you define your dataTable, there's a function of the dataTable object named "makeEditable()", and within that function are a couple of other optional functions, "fnOnEditing()" and "fnOnEdited()". These functions can be used to preserve the new text in the td cell.

What I did was first define a global variable, so that the new text can be captured and stored inside fnOnEditing(), right before the cell's text is changed, and then in fnOnEdited() it can be retrieved and placed back as that cell's text.

See code below for the general idea.

```
    //define global variables
    var latestText;
    var editRowID;
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').dataTable({
            [ColumnDefs, other config options]
             }).makeEditable({
                  [settings for if/how each column can be edited],
                  fnOnEditing: function(input, oEditableSettings, sOriginalText, id) {
                       //this function is run right before the edit is executed
                       //capture the edited row's id and the text in the cell 
                       editRowID = id;
                       latestText = $('#myTDCell_row' + editRowID).text();
                  },
                  fnOnEdited: function(status, sOldValue, sNewCellDisplayValue, aPos0, aPos1, aPos2) {
                       //this function runs after the edit has been made
                      /* the edit has been made to some cell in the row, and the text in our cell (which is another cell in that same row) has reverted to what it was before we changed it. So now we immediately change it back */
                      $('#myTDCell_row' + editRowID).text(latestText);
                  },
                  sUpdateURL: [path to page that handles the actual back-end DB update; a request is made to this page as soon as you click the enter key]
});
```